# How do I write idle animations in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to code a platformer game using pygame.
I have tried to add idle animations to my character but it always seems to overlap with the other animations I have for running.

```
    def update(self):
    dx = 0
    dy = 0
    walk_cooldown = 1
    

    #get keypresses
    key = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if key[pygame.K_SPACE] and self.jumped == False:
        self.vel_y= -15
        self.jumped =True

    if key[pygame.K_SPACE] == False:
        self.jumped = False
        
    if key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        dx -= 10
        self.counter += 1
        self.direction = -1

    if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        dx += 10
        self.counter += 1
        self.direction = 1

    if key[pygame.K_LEFT] == False and key[pygame.K_RIGHT] == False:
        self.counter = 0
        self.index = 0
        if self.direction == 1:
            self.image = self.images_right[self.index]
        if self.direction == -1:
            self.image = self.images_left[self.index]
            


        

    #handle animation
    if self.counter > walk_cooldown:
        self.counter = 0
        self.index += 1
        if self.index >= len(self.images_right):
            self.index = 0
        if self.direction == 1:
            self.image = self.images_right[self.index]
        if self.direction == -1:
            self.image = self.images_left[self.index]
```

What is the best way I should add them? I have all the images for the animations ready in the background my main problem is trying to get them to work at the right times. I also have jumping animations I needed to add and that too seems to be a problem for me.

Any advice will be helpful,
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I program a game, I usually create an `is_walking` variable which is false when the player is idle and true when the player is walking. Then you can modify part of the code to do the following:

```
    if key[pygame.K_LEFT] == False and key[pygame.K_RIGHT] == False and not (is_walking):
        self.counter = 0
        self.index = 0
        if self.direction == 1:
            self.image = self.images_right[self.index]
        if self.direction == -1:
            self.image = self.images_left[self.index]
```

This should get your code to the point where it only does the idle animation if you aren't walking and vice versa.